# Centering content of div in a container

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

In my website, i have a series of divs like this:

```
.box{
   float:left;
   width:143px;
   height:183px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

These divs are inside a simple container like this:

```
.container{
   margin:70px 190px 0 190px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

I would realize a responsive layout but the divs are not horizontal centered in the container. I tried to add "margin-left:auto;" and "margin-right:auto" but nothing. I have a layout as this:

[image]

Instead, i would a layout as this:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: It would be good if you could create [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of your code. Will be solved fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using FlexBox.

**[FlexBox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

**[FlexBox Browsers Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)**

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  
    margin:7px 19px 0 19px;
    background-color: red;
}

.box {
    width:143px;
    height:183px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoting because flexbox is designed specifically for this kind of layout ;)

Comment: That is actually a pretty cool solution. I too learned something today :)

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/rsswou6e/8/)

You can achieve this using `display:inline-block;`, So kindly remove the `float:left` used in your CSS.

I have made an example like below,

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
    margin:10px;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: It will center align the items in last row, too.

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle it is left aligned..i think that is due to some issue with your CSS. Could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this using `float`. You can use `display: inline-block`.

```
.box{
    width:143px;
    height:183px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container{
    margin:70px 190px 0 190px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but removing float i have only an element below the other...

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{  
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box{
    float:left;
    width: 31%;
    height: 183px;  
    background: #f00;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```